# About an example of law of total expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_0,X_1$,... be defined as:

1).start with a stick of length $X_0$.

2). If we have a stick of length $X_n$, break it at a uniformly randomly chosen point of $X_{n+1}$ be the length of the longer piece.

Given $X_n=x$, and let Y be the breaking position, and Y is $\mathcal{U}(0,x)$, and $X_{n+1}=\max({Y,x-Y})$.

Problem 1: $Find E(X_{n+1}|X_n=x)$

We get $E(X_{n+1}|X_n=x)=E(\max({y,x-Y}|X_n=x))=\int_0^x \max${y,x-y}$*\frac{1}{x} dy= \frac{3}{4}x=\frac{3}{4}X_n$. Hence $E(X_n)= (\frac{3}{4})^n E(X_0)$(by law of total expectation)

> Question: I don't get how  $\frac{3}{4}x$ arrives

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ using `\max`. For operators without a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Note that $$\max\{y,x-y\} = \begin{cases}x-y & \text{ if } y \leq x/2 \\ y & \text{ if } y > x/2\end{cases}$$  Do you know how to evaluate the integral of a piecewise function?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thx!